# How to make AndroidAnnotations-generated class accept a WeakReference<Activity> instead of Activity in its constructor

Tags: android, android-annotations

I have a `@EBean` (by AndroidAnnotations) annotated class that extends `BaseAdapter`. I haven't provided any constructors, but the generated class creates one and it accepts the `Activity` as its argument.

A background task loads the content and in cases where it hasn't finished before the activity is killed, it leaks the `Activity` context. Usually, when I am in control, I pass `WeakReference<Activity>` to such background tasks and the problem no longer occurs, but here I can't control what the generated constructor accepts as its argument, can I?

Is there a way to fix this?

A fragment uses this adapter, and this is how the generated version of the fragment instantiates the adapter:

```
adapter = MyAdapter_.getInstance_(getActivity());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These generated methods are not designed to be consumed by the programmer, they are actually implementation details for AA. Of course you can call them if you want, but you will not be able to achieve the question in the OP.

Comment: Yes, I am not going to start messing with the generated methods, of course, I just went there to see what is going on and I found out what happens. So is there a way to avoid this memory leak?